# Convert Redirectmatch to RewriteRule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to put a line in our subdirectory www.example.com/us/ htaccess file (not the root htaccess) to get www.example.com/us and www.example.com/us/ to redirect to www.example.com, but nothing else -- so www.example.com/us/file.txt or www.example.com/dir/file.txt would not redirect.

I tried:

```
RedirectMatch ^/us$ http://www.example.com/
RedirectMatch ^/us/$ http://www.example.com/
```

but it caused a loop because of other Rewrite conditions in the file (I think).

I tried converting to RewriteRule as follows

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^us(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

No luck.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^us/?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

No luck.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you trying to redirect to `/$1`, if you want to go to `/` actually? Besides, you second rule doesn’t even capture anything, so using a back reference doesn’t even make sense there.

Comment: If I knew how to make it work, I wouldn't be asking questions.

Can you offer a suggestion?

Comment: @user3879788 Always glad to help :) Please mark this answer as accepted, then people will now it is solved and I will really appreciate :) It is the tick below the number two and the arrows on the left :) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/us/*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much. (My first question on stackoverflow answered in minutes -- amazing.)

Comment: @user3879788 Always glad to help :) Please mark this answer as accepted, then people will now it is solved and I will really appreciate :) It is the tick below the number two and the arrows on the left :) thanks.